# Twig Variable Variables for a method

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm attempting to do something that was very easy in PHP, but not so easy in twig.

Basically, I need to call a class method, but I need to be able to define the method to call via a string.

I have 3 methods: `getControlvs`, `getControlnc` and `getControltr`. However, in order to call these methods, I need a seperate variable which determines which one to call.

This is what I'm attempting to call right now:

```
{% set neutPer = key.getControl~neutFaction %}
```

Where `neutFaction` can be either "vs", "nc", or "tr".

This only seems to fire key.getControl and then that's it, the concatenation is lost.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: check the [attribute](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/attribute.html#attribute) function

Comment: @Matteo I've seen that come up in my research on this, but it's very unclear to me how to actually use it. Doesn't help when there's no examples on how to use it :S

Comment: of course, i try to give you an example

Comment: @Matteo I think I've figured it out:

`{% set neutPer = attribute(key, neutKey) %}`

Comment: yes, also. Depends how you can build the string of the method name

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [attribute twig function](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/attribute.html#attribute):

First concatenate the string as:

```
{% set method = "getControl" ~ neutFaction %}
```

Then call as

```
{{ attribute(key, method) }}
```

You can pass arguments also as:

```
{{ attribute(key, method, arguments) }}
```

In addition, the defined test can check for the existence of a dynamic attribute:

```
{{ attribute(object, method) is defined ? 'Method exists' : 'Method does not exist' }}
```

Comment: For those looking for the final code I got, here's the correct code: `{% set neutFaction = 'vs' %}  {% set neutKey = 'getControl'~neutFaction %} {% set neutPer = attribute(key, neutKey) %}`

Answer (score -1):

Try `{% set neutPer = (key.getControl~neutFaction) %}`
Or you could change this in your controller/service that passes the variable to twig so that you do not need to setup a concatenation.