# Adding prefix to a dynamic tag

Tags: twig, twig.js

I need some help with the following implementation. I wanted to add a prefix to my dynamic tag and then want twig to fetch the value for this tag.

```
{% set result = 'text.journey_service_'~ data.addServ.serviceName %}

{{ result }}

Actual output => text.journey_service_SMALL_PET

Expected output => {{ text.journey_service_SMALL_PET }} = > Dog
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Twig Variable Variables for a method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29283751/twig-variable-variables-for-a-method)

Comment: @DarkBee I don't think this is a pure duplicate, as building the `result` variable is already broken

Comment: @Nico can't argue with that, but OP is showing us  "actual" output, meaning the example he posted is not the code he is actualy using, because his example indeed contains a syntax error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not look valid:

```
{% set result = 'text.journey_service_'~{{ data.addServ.serviceName }} %}
```

If you want to concatenate a string and a variable, you should better use:

```
{% set result = 'text.journey_service_'~ data.addServ.serviceName %}
```

If you want to use `result` as the variable name to print something, you can use the following code (as given in [Twig: Print the value of a variable where the variable name is String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30347230/twig-print-the-value-of-a-variable-where-the-variable-name-is-string)):

```
{{ attribute(_context, result) }}
```

Comment: @DarkBee thanks for pointing that out, I've added another call

Comment: should be `{{ attribute(text, journey_service_'~ data.addServ.serviceName }}` though as you are now looking for the variable `text.journey_service_SMALL_PET` which doesn't exist.

Comment: I don't know which variable could or could not exist, but the given variable `text.journey_service_SMALL_PET` is the one used in the question. That must not be a variable after all, it could also be something transferred to the view using some parameter array

Comment: @HamadGondal please explain that further. I've edited my answer several minutes ago to highlight further details. But as DarkBee already asked: is `text` a variable or object on its own?

Comment: @NicoHaase i am new to twig. Thanks for the correction now its gives me the text "text.journey_service_SMALL_PET" i want this text to be the input and translate it to Dog

Comment: Is there any reason to use Twig for this? Looks like you put too much work into your templating engine, work that should be done by your controller?

Comment: @DarkBee Thank you so much ... the following code worked and i got my desired answer 
 {{ attribute(text, 'journey_service_'~ data.addServ.serviceName) }}